# How to change the line breaks into another character in html text areas in python?

Tags: python, django, textarea

I have a django website where user can enter recipes in a textarea. When I want the user to enter each step of the recipe in a different line in the text area, how to I detect and change the line breaks into '\n' when entering into the database so that when later he downloads he recipe in the form of a text file, he should see each step in different line there as well.

Right now, it joins all the text together when inserting into database. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The [linebreaks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks) template tag is used to render newlines (from text fields) into html breaks.

```
{{ some_text|linebreaks }}
```

If some_text == `Recipe\nIngredient 1- Cilantro` the rendered output will be `Recipe<br/>Ingrediant 1- Cilantro`.

Comment: Its not about rendering the data. Its about inputting it in database. I am trying to replace the line breaks into '\n'

Comment: Are you using a [TextField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.TextField) to store the data?

Comment: TextField should store newlines automatically, unless you are using a custom widget or validation that strips them. If you look at what is being stored in the database, what is in the place where you would expect newlines?